# How to put two logos on the same line, opposite sides of page, on top of watermark?

Tags: graphics, titles, logos, watermark, kaobook

I am using the [kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook) class, and I am having trouble with getting the title page look as I want it to.

I produced for you a [minimal working example](https://ufile.io/uht6ffrk), which you can easily compile on overleaf. I would like the first page to look like this:

1. The two Disney logos on the same line, and opposite sides (left/right) of the page, on page 1.
2. The watermark with the star chart on the bottom as a background, on page 1.
3. The title text in the third page on top of the watermark and below the logos, on page 1.

Do you know how do to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Can you *post* a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: Your minimal working example is neither minimal nor working: `Undefined control sequence \theoremstyle`

Comment: If you found the answer satisfactory, please accept it.

Comment: There is a (gray) checkmark to click, bellow the pointing down  triangle, on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simplified example.

Use

```
\titlehead{%
    \includegraphics[height=2.7cm,keepaspectratio]{logo1.jpg}\hfill\includegraphics[height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo2.png}
}
```

and

```
\SetWatermarkText{\tikz{\node[opacity=0.2]{\includegraphics[width=35cm,angle=30]{watermark_blurred.png}}}}
```

before `\maketitle`

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    fontsize=11pt, 
    twoside=true,
    numbers=noenddot, 
]{kaobook}

\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkLightness{1}
\SetWatermarkScale{1.6}

\usepackage[framed=true]{kaotheorems}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{kaorefs} % must be the last <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text <<<<<

\begin{document}

%------------------------
\titlehead{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \includegraphics[height=2.7cm,keepaspectratio]{logo1.jpg}\hfill\includegraphics[height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo2.png}
}

\subject{
\textit{This goes above the title}}

\title[]{\fontsize{50}{1}\selectfont This is the title}

\author[This is the author]{This is the author}

\date{\today}

\frontmatter 
\SetWatermarkText{\tikz{\node[opacity=0.2]{\includegraphics[width=35cm,angle=30]{watermark_blurred.png}}}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\maketitle

\pagelayout{wide}

\mainmatter 
\setchapterstyle{kao}

\chapter{First}

\kant[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm!

Comment: I don't know how to do it